# css drop down div not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a div that when you mouseover has a child div appear to display information.  The basic code is as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="hidden_div">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    top: 8px;
    left: 30px;
}

#hidden_div {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../_images/inside_btn_back.png) repeat;
    height: 60px;
    width: 350px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    z-index: 50;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #a08f89;
}

#container:hover #hidden_div, #container.over #hidden_div, #container:focus #hidden_div {
    display: block;
}
```

This works in all browsers except IE(specifically IE9).  I have a navigation window using the same method for a drop down menu that works fine in IE. don't know why its not working with the div.  Here is a link to the live page [here](http://www.envisiodesigns.com/test/).  The mouse over div is the facebook like button near the bottom of the page.

Comment: I just tried it in IE, it works perfectly in IE9, has no content in IE8 fails in IE7 and fails in Quirks mode.

Comment: what's `z-index` for? also instead of `top: 0px; margin-top: 20px;` you could only use - in your case - `top:100%`

Comment: When I open my page in IE9 the mouseover works until you try to mouseover the hidden div, the div then disappears, which makes it so you can't actually click the facebook like button.

Comment: Z-index is to make sure the hidden div displays above other content.

Comment: Just want to clear something up, Z-Index is used for "depth". It makes things display in front of, or behind each other. The higher the z-index, the closer it is to the front. "...displays above other content" makes me think that you're talking about the vertical plane (y-axis) when, in fact, you're talking about the depth plane (z-axis).

Comment: Yes I meant above in the sense that it appears closer to the viewer.  I should think that the z in z-index would be an obvious reference to the z-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the page loaded in the iframe not having a transparent background which causes the hover to fail in IE.