# Nav menu sitting behind iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-9

Specifically on IE9 only, my navigation menu is sitting behind my iframe when viewing a PDF through that iFrame.

I have set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/q6fmv/

Alternatively please see the bottom of this question for the code.

When viewed on IE9 if you hover over the navigation elements, the ones that have a sub nav you can see are hidden behind the iFrame.

I have tried setting the z-index of the nav menu to be higher than that of the iFrame but it didnt work.

How can I resolve this so the sub menu of the navigatino menu appears on top of the iframe?

HTML

```
<div id="navMenu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="iframe">
    <iframe name="myiFrame" width="100%" height="100%" title="My iFrame" id="myIframe" src="http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf" frameBorder="0"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*Initialize*/
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

Have also tried using PDFObject.js http://jsfiddle.net/q6fmv/10/. It didnt work

Comment: Hmm, interesting, variations of `z-index` don't work. I wonder if using this method will allow you to `z-index` the `ul` tags: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974315/1045794

Comment: possible duplicate of [z-index does not work in IE7/IE8 with pdf in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911428/z-index-does-not-work-in-ie7-ie8-with-pdf-in-iframe)

Comment: I have seen that, but the solution doesnt work. thats a simple div, this is a drop down nav menu.

Comment: I wonder if it acts like a flash object, google something like `wmode iframe`, I've put divs over flash objects that have similar properties. *Might* do the trick.

Comment: FYI just tried the pdfobject idea. didnt work. http://jsfiddle.net/q6fmv/10/

Comment: Now it should work :) You can test it. Check my answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the empty iframe technique ?
It was not working before because you need to add an empty iframe inside each submenu ul tag.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
    <div id="navMenu">    
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <iframe class="cover" src="about:blank"></iframe>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                     <iframe class="cover" src="about:blank"></iframe>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            </li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  #outer {
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;    
    z-index: 3;
}

    #inner{
        background: red;
    }

    .cover {
        position: absolute;
        border: none;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -2;
        height:100%;
    }

#pdf {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index:3;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}

/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}

/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    z-index:3;
}

ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/gDuCE/701/

Comment: If i visit your jsfiddle on ie9 it still has the same problem

Comment: @AlexIncarnati Nice, +1

Answer (score 1):

I have used google docs code for embedding via iframe to the website.

I have added jsfiddle link which you can directly check in ie9.

[JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/nVxUK/1/)

[JSFiddle fullscreen code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/nVxUK/1/embedded/result/) - check this directly in ie9

If you are using google documents as iframe, then please do make sure that it is shared publicly.

```
<div id="navMenu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="iframe">
    <!--<iframe name="myiFrame" width="100%" height="100%" title="My iFrame" id="myIframe" src="http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf" frameBorder="0"/>-->
   <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByF4RjDx3q6sMW9DWHR0MXNtN0k/preview" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe> 
</div>
```

Regards D.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding position and z-index to `#menu` or `#navMenu` as such

```
ul#menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q6fmv/7/

I don't have IE9 to check though