# Pdf in Iframe overlapping top navigation bar in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe

I am working on asp.net webform with a masterpage. The master page has a top navigation bar and a side bar. beside side bar i called contentplaceholder in which i've put an iframe. in that iframe i am opening the pdf-file "files.pdf" in an iframe; it is working fine with other browsers but when i open this page in internet explorer, the iframe overlaps the top menu :( kindly help me to resolve this issue .

Here is my Master Page Code

```asp
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div id="wrapper" class="mywrapper">
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <!-- Fixed navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index:2;">
              ......
            </nav>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3" style="z-index:2;">
                    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">                   
                        <div class="sidebar-nav">
                           ...................
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9" style="background-color: #FFF; z-index:1;" >
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my Content aspx Page

```asp
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="height:1000px;">
        <iframe id="myiframe" class="embed-responsive-item" runat="server"  ></iframe>        
    </div>    
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my Content cs Page

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PageToOpen = Request.QueryString.Get("open");
    myiframe.Attributes.Add("src", PageToOpen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the iframe wmode to "opaque"

```
<iframe ... wmode="opaque"></iframe>
```

See 
[z-index does not work in Internet Explorer with pdf in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911428/z-index-does-not-work-in-internet-explorer-with-pdf-in-iframe) 
and 
[YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index/9074366#9074366)

Also, it's hard to tell when you don't show us the styles you have defined.
 
But it's most-likely an issue with the z-index.

Never mind, seems to be for flash video only. 
Just set a div with the height of the navigation bar before the iframe (the blue div).
That way, you shouldn't need the z-index.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Test
    </title>


    <style type="text/css">


        html, body
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }


        .navbar-fixed-top
        {
            position: fixed;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            height: 50px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .sidebar
        {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            height: 900px;
            background-color: green;
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="wrapper" class="mywrapper">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <!-- Fixed navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index:2;">
                ......
            </nav>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3" style="z-index:2;">
                    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                        <div class="sidebar-nav">
                            ...................
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9" style="background-color: #FFF; z-index:1; background-color: yellow;">
                    <div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 60px; background-color: blue;">aaaa</div>
                    <iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" style="width: 80%; height: 500px; border: none;"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- End Row -->
        </div><!-- End Wrapper -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's showing me error wmode is not the valid attribute of iframe element

Comment: @Alina Anjum: Then just put a div with appropriate height before the iframe. That way the iframe is pushed down, and you don't need the z-index. BTW: Is that a Pakistani or a Quatari name ?

Comment: yes, i am trying the same sir thanks.and Its Pakistani name :)

Comment: @Alina Anjum: Good luck, and don't call me "sir", I'm not your boss, nor that old )))

Comment: I got the solution from this idea..Thanks a lot ))

Comment: I've tried to asked the same in other questions as well,you could answer them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000383/open-pdf-file-in-iframe-internet-explorer-issue

Comment: @Alina Anjum: Why did you do that ? It makes little sense asking the same question multiple times - it usually won't get an answer faster. Instead, add more detail to one question, so that the problem can be easily reproduced - then you'll get an answer faster. When you don't provide the styles, e.g. what navbar-fixed-top does, then it's time consuming to reproduce the problem, and we all have day jobs with deadlines, too. Also, properly tag it. If you had tagged it HTML & CSS & InternetExplorer, you'd probably have gotten a better answer far more quickly. Your problem has little to do with C#

Comment: actually i was not getting any response to my question that's why i did that but i'll take care next time.. thanks for your suggestion ))