# Unable to place a div over iframe in IE

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am placing divs and iframes using position `relative` & `absolute` which is working fine on chrome but its not working in IE. I am using `Foxit Reader` in IE to show the pdf files.

**Chrome** (Test 1231 23123 is visible)
[image: chrome]

**IE 11** (Test 1231 23123 is behind the iframe)

[image]

Below is my html:

```
 <div class="document-previewer-container">
 <div class="document-preview">
    <div class="document-container">
        <iframe id="pdf-container" ng-attr-src="{{vm.selectedDoc.pdfpath`}}"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="doc-overlay">
        <p>Test 1231 23123</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="documents-carousel-wrapper">
    <!-- something -->
 </div>
</div>
```

my `.less` file:

@import '../../styles/light-theme-definitions.less';

```
div.document-previewer-container {
//height: 400px;
//width: 300px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
//padding: 5px 2px;
> div.document-preview {
    height: 88%;
    //width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    .document-container{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .doc-overlay {
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;

        p {
            padding: 2px;
        }
    }
}

> div.documents-carousel-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 12%;
    min-height: 63px;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

### Update: 1

Working [PLUNKER. Please open it with IE or save it on ur local disk and open it with IE](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nyxc9KdAJCWLTKFjMjXo?p=preview)

### Update: 2

I implemented the logic but still the div is not coming over pdf `iframe`. Please try clicking anywhere on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YskcRqsVFPhD1Ac2A8yO?p=preview).

Actually, I want the `doc-overlay` to be clickable in real life project. As u'll observe, the click event (using ng-click) is not working over PDF. Please refer the *inspect element* screenshot for more clarity. [IE](http://i66.tinypic.com/28uh9nm.jpg) & [Chrome](http://i63.tinypic.com/2ppm3hs.jpg). checkout the blue area too see the difference

Comment: Have you played around with the CSS z-index property? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: @Webbanditten: Yep, it's not working :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-index does not work in Internet Explorer with pdf in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911428/z-index-does-not-work-in-internet-explorer-with-pdf-in-iframe)

Comment: I tested your updated code and it didnt work, which resulted me to Google a little since I could see that the z-index had no effect - I found the answer and marked your post as Possible duplicate - I got it working btw. Using the thread I linked to.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @Webbanditten, please refer Update 2.

Answer (score -1):

You need to either do a hack where you add another iFrame or use library like PDF.js as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977151/8833279